# Block doesn't show up in blocks listing

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

Custom block doesn't show up on block listing and pages allowed to display that block.
After switch theme everything is ok, so it is not module layer issue.

I check template.php everything seems to be ok. I check CSS (display: none, etc), it seems that it's not CSS issue.

I asked about other idea's, why that block doesn't show up? I am struggling few hours and starting to have no new idea's to solved that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure the region variable is getting printed in `page.tpl.php` which is associated with your block.
- Make sure there is content for your block. If `$block['content']` is set to empty in hook_block then the block does not appear at all.
- Check block visibility condition as well

Comment: I need to set manually region column in db of this block. Now it's display on blocks listing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to watch out for is the possibility of overriding `hook_block()` through configuration in the ui.

If you don't get it right first time in `hook_block()`, subsequent changes to your code won't be reflected - you have to delete the entry for that block in the database first.

Setting the region as it's machine name in the theme's `.info` file is important too.