# Block not showing up in Custom Blocks for Panel

Tags: blocks, panels

I've made a simple text block and now want to display this on a panel. However, the block does not appear on the list of available blocks on the Custom Block page. I've tried clearing the cache, and making different blocks, but it appears that all new blocks aren't showing up in that menu.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I found this disucssion, [Block doesn't show up in blocks listing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5166/block-doesnt-show-up-in-blocks-listing). But I don't really understand what their solution was (manually edit db entry?).

Comment: Same here - but I am running the same site on a different server and there it works as expected. So it seems like it's some small setting or code problem in my case.

Comment: I take that back - same problem on all servers. A couple of custom blocks show, but blocks added after a certain point do not show.

Comment: Are you creating this block through drupal's block admin? (structure/block)? If so, what's the url for your block config look like (should be soemthing like /admin/structure/block/manage/block/2/configure)

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same issue. Is it an issue with the number of blocks that are added, i.e., too many?

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom block from code and it is listed in "miscellaneous" section insted of "custom blocks". Maybe your modules are there.

Answer (score 2):

When my custom block wasn’t showing, it was because there were unsaved changes to the Panel and it was locked.

After clicking "cancel" to remove the changes and unlock the Panel, the custom block then appears within the "Miscellaneous" section.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://margotskapacs.com/2013/10/blocks-in-drupal/) should point you to right direction, specifically the `hook_block_info` that is implemented at the beginning of the article.

On panel menu, the created block should fall into "Miscellaneous" tab.